# how can i add comment to @Column or to @Table in eclipselink jpa?

Tags: jpa

Somebody said that the script below is avaliable. but how to do with eclipselink2.5,thanks.
@Column(name="username",columnDefinition=("varchar(50)  default null comment 'login name'"))

Comment: columnDefinition=("varchar(50) default null comment 'login name'" should be effect in hibernate jpa.

Comment: application server is Glassfish4.0 and dbms is Oracle 11g